# Что такое смещение в Ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, память, nasm

изучаю язык ассемблера в реализации NASM. Не понимаю что такое смещение, то есть записи в виде:
`mov eax, [bp+di]`
знаю что eax - это регистр, bp и di Тоже регистры размером в 16 бит. bp - это база, di -  это индекс, но понимания на деле ноль. По сути запись сверху означает что в регистр eax помещается значение по адресу [bp+di]? И это всё ещё теоретическое понятие, не понимаю как это применимо к конкретной задаче:

I1 = 124, I2 = -5665, R1 = BX, данный мне вариант косвенной адресации [BP+DI]

**Задать такие операции пересылки данных:
– загрузить регистр R1 числом I2 из сегмента данных;
– с использованием заданного варианта косвенной
адресации записать содержимое R1 в сегмент данных со
смещением на I1 байт относительно метки I2 (число I1
предварительно загрузить в соответствующий базовый или
индексный регистр, при наличии других операндов в формуле
адресации определить их произвольно).*

у меня есть такой код:

```
    section .data

I1 db 124
I2 dw -5665

section .bss
I3 resw 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov bx, word [I2]
    mov bp, word [I2]
    mov di, word [I1]
    ;mov bp, I1
    ;mov bx, [bp+di*8+I2]
    ;mov [I3], eax
    ;mov [I3], bx
    mov [bp+di], bx

    int 0x80        ; вызов ядра    
    mov eax,1       ; номер системного вызова (sys_exit)
    int 0x80
```

Он выдаёт мне ошибки:
*hello.asm:27: error: impossible combination of address sizes
hello.asm:27: error: invalid effective address*

Проблема несоответствия размеров которые я пихаю, но я вообще не понимаю, я же использую 16-битные регистры и максимальное значение переменной это dw = 16 бит. И сами смещения? что куда я смещаю совершенно не понимаю :(. Желательно объяснить и абстрактно и на примере данной задачи очень доходчиво(((

Comment: https://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/asm_i8086_28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идёт о смещении, значит должна быть и база.
То-есть смещение всегда задаётся относительно какого-то адреса.
Возьмём к примеру любой дамп в HEX-редакторе, типа:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  0C 5A 3F FF C8 37 00 10  00 00 00 00 00 3F 00 00  .Z?яИ7.......?..
00000010  00 00 00 00 35 4A 56 34  4C 39 37 36 20 20 20 20  ....5JV4L976    
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  00 00 10 00 00 04 33 2E          ......3.
00000030  30 36 20 20 20 20 53 54  33 38 30 30 31 31 41 20  06    ST380011A 
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
00000050  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 80 10                Ђ.
00000060  00 00 2F 00 00 00 02 00  02 00 00 07 3F FF 00 10  ../.........?я..
00000070  00 3F FC 10 00 FB 01 10  F8 B0 09 50 00 00 00 07  .?ь..ы..ш°.P....
00000080  00 03 00 78 00 78 00 F0  00 78 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...x.x.р.x......
```

В данном случае базой считается нуль и далее видим, что:

- по смещению(14h) начинается строка "5JV4L976"
- по смещению(36h) начинается строка "ST380011A"
- по смещению(5Eh) лежит  byte со-значением `80h`
- по смещению(78h) лежит  word со-значением `B0F8h`
- по смещению(80h) лежит dword со-значением `78000300h`, и т.д.

Это пример с сохранённым в файл дампом, а потому база здесь нуль, т.е. начало файла. Но в процессе программирования вы будете выделять память динамически. Тогда значение базы определяет уже сама система, в зависимости от свободных (на данный момент) участков этой памяти.

Теперь смотрим на описание вашей задачи. Минусы задач из учебников в том, что их авторы не могут (ленятся) толком выразить свою мысль, в результате чего возникает путаница. Если переформулировать эту задачу, то получаем следующее:

> i1 = 124, i2 = -5665, R1 = BX
>
> Задать такие операции пересылки данных:
>
> - загрузить в регистр BX число с переменной i2;
> - с использованием косвенной адресации [BP+DI], записать содержимое BX со смещением на i1 байт, относительно метки i2.

Решение:

```
section .data
i1   dw    124
i2   dw   -5665

section .text
global _start

_start:
     mov   bx, [i2]         ;// загрузить в ВХ число i2
     mov   bp, i2           ;// BP = адрес базы (т.к. сказано "..относительно метки i2")
     mov   di, [i1]         ;// DI = смещение относительно базы
     mov   word[bp+di], bx  ;// записать BX со смещением на i1 байт, относительно метки i2

;//     int   0x80            ;// Ошибка! вызов ядра без номера функции в EAX
     mov   eax,1            ;// sys_exit
     int   0x80
```

Comment: Да, я так и поняла так и делала, спасибо большое. Ещё вопрос, если мы делаем mov eax, i2 то это мы кладём значение i2 в регистр, а если mov eax, [i2] то адрес ячейки?

Comment: Наоборот: `mov eax,[i2]` - это берём в `EAX` значение из переменной, а `mov eax,i2` - это адрес переменной. То-есть если в квадратных скобках, это значение из памяти, а без скобок - это адрес.

Comment: спасибо большое